# Excluding certain traffic from TrafficStats calculation

Tags: android

I am using [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) to monitor the data usage of my app. It works fine as of now.

But I want to send this data over the newtork to my server in real time (like per second usage). If I just use the code as it is, the traffic to my server from my app will also be added to the bytes sent and received. This is not desired. I want to exclude the data being sent to my server.

A possible solution is that my app could create another "app", thereby creating a new UID. Then, I can monitor only the parent app's TrafficStats. But this would require a lot of code changing and some side effects (like one app being killed/paused while the other isn't).

I could also use the method `TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(int tag)` method to tag a socket
and use only the tagged socket for network operations to my server. Then I could subtract this from the total to get the desired result. Please help me on how can I implement this.

Another solution could be to monitor received and sent by my server so that I can subtract this from data containing traffic per second. But the problem is that I cannot understand how much to subtract from a particular interval of per second data.

Any ideas on my mentioned possible solutions or any another solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread and Socket tagging is possible for DDMS purposes to allow the profiling and debugging of your own applications. In this case you will need to specify which threads/sockets you want to be tagged and then the data will be outputted to the DDMS.
Please notice that this is only fully supported from Android 4.0.3.
You can find detailed information regarding the implementation [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/detailednetworkusageinddms)

In case you are interested in tracking your own app data usage, without including the data generated by the reporting mechanism, you could create another app to track your app data usage. In that case, you will need to implement some hack that will bypass the TrafficStats API which is currently broken for Android 4.3 and does not allow you the stats collection for other UIDs than your own.
You can see this thread to understand further and you can find the exact solution [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/detailednetworkusageinddms)

If you know exactly how much traffic is generated by your reporting mechanism, you could monitor your own app using the TrafficStats API on your process UID, and subtract that amount from the result. The TrafficStats API allows currently on TCP bytes extraction, which means that you could calculate using Wireshark/tcpdump the amount of TCP bytes sent for your reporting mechanism.